# nginx and uWSGI gives "504 Gateway timeout"

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am following the tutorial [Setting up Django and your web server with uWSGI and nginx](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html).

### uWSGI is up and running

I set up uwsgi to serve my Django project with the following line.

```
mydjangoproj $ uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8002 --module wsgi --harakiri 5
```

This works when I go there in a browser, to `42.42.42.42:8002`.

### My nginx setup

nginx is running as a daemon, and visiting it's default site, port 80, works.

I added this as a site to nginx using the following `mydjangoproj_nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name 42.42.42.42;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /static {
        alias /home/myuser/mydjangoproj/static; 
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8002;
        include     /home/myuser/mydjangoproj/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I use the unmodified version of `uwsgi_params`, from the tutorial:

```
uwsgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
uwsgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
uwsgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
uwsgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
uwsgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
uwsgi_param PATH_INFO $document_uri;
uwsgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
uwsgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param HTTPS $https if_not_empty;
uwsgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
uwsgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
uwsgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
```

It does serve the static files perfectly.

### Error

If I visit 42.42.42.42:8000 it hangs for a long time, until the nginx timeout I guess, and I get `504 Gateway Time-out`.

uWSGI writes nothing in the shell. If visiting directly in browser, it does write about receiving a request.

The nginx error log writes, only after the timeout:

```
2014/12/11 05:31:12 [error] 28895#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 66.66.66.66, server: 42.42.42.42, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://42.42.42.42:8002", host: "42.42.42.42:8000"
```

If I close the uWSGI, which is just run from a shell, I instantly get a `502 Bad Gateway`.

When searching online, people just recommend setting the uWSGI timeout lower than the nginx timeout, that's why I run uWSGI with `--harakiri 5`.

So, what is my problem here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you are running uwsgi in http mode `--http 0.0.0.0:8002` but you have configured nginx as uwsgi proxy. You should change your uwsgi script to something like:

```
 uwsgi --socket :8002 --module uwsgi --harakiri 5
```

Note that if you are running `nginx` and `uwsgi` on the same machine is better to use [unix sockets](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#using-unix-sockets-instead-of-ports)

Comment: That did it! I thought the communication between nginx and uwsgi should be http, but apparently is is a different kind of connection.

Comment: I normally wait a few days for other answers to pop up, and then pick the best one. I don't know if this is against guidelines. But I've marked it answered now :)

Comment: how is --harakiri 5 different from --socket-timeout 5 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67407446/oserror-write-error-python-flask-sigpipe-writing-to-a-closed-pipe-socket-fd