# (nginx + uwsgi + django). nginx server is not allowing the request to hit the uwsgi server

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

**I am not getting any reply from ngix**

**nginx logs**

2016/05/23 15:19:49 [error] 9019#0: *3 upstream timed out (110:          Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.171.107.80, server: 54.169.34.178, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "54.169.34.178"

Previously I was only using uwsgi server, Now I want to add nginx at the front so that it can serve the static data and act as api-gateway.

I am trying to use this [tutoriall](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html). I was able to run the uwsgi server seperatly and when i combine it with nginx it's not working.

Can any one please help me on?

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

**sites-enabled/*.conf**

```

```
upstream testing {
server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
listen      80;

    server_name 54.169.34.178 
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste


    location / {
       uwsgi_pass testing;
        include     /home/ubuntu/testDjango/testWeb/uwsgi_params; 
    }
```

}

```

Comment: you get this error while nginx is trying to serve static content or while it is proxying to your uwsgi server ?

Comment: Currently I am not serving static content seperately. I am just trying to get the home page, which has all the necessery page in the single file

Comment: http://54.169.34.178:8000/ works fine for me on which I am running uwsgi. I am trying hit it by http://54.169.34.178/, But it doesn't work

Comment: can you please tell a bit about your uwsgi config like the host and port it binds to ?

Comment: As of now, I am running like

uwsgi --http :8000 --module testWeb.wsgi

It works when you hit ipaddress:8000

Comment: I think the answer might be here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424043/671057 tldr: `uwsgi --socket :8002 --module wsgi.py`

Answer (score 0):

As per the config and details you shared it seams like you are using uwsgi server which is bound to 0.0.0.0 (because you can access it here 54.169.34.178:8000) while in your nginx config you are setting upstream to 127.0.0.1. which is why nginx cannot reach your application.

I would suggest you to run your application at 127.0.0.1 by using the following command
`uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8000 --module testWeb.wsgi`

now try to access `http://54.169.34.178/` from your browser.

Comment: I am getting the same error, Now I am unable to point the uwsgi even. When i tried Ipadderess:8000/- It doesn't work. 
And Nginx throwing the same error.

Comment: did you try `uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8000 --module testWeb.wsgi`.
here ipaddress is not any ipaddress but you localhost i.e. 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Yes I did that(uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8000 --module testWeb.wsgi). I am running in ec2 so just trying to hit http://54.169.34.178:8000/-, An I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: you should try `54.169.34.178:80` or just `54.169.34.178` because your nginx is listening on port 80. Now when nginx will receive a http request it will forward it to the upstream which in your case in `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Comment: I understand that nginx is listening on port 80, I just want to check whether my backend application is working or not.

when I hit the nginx now, I am getting the follwing error
2016/05/23 16:47:59 [error] 12078#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.171.107.80, server: 54.169.34.178, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "54.169.34.178"
~

Comment: for further debugging I would suggest you to ssh into your ec-instance and test using curl.
`curl http://127.0.0.1:8000`
If curl works that means your service is running properly. Now go ahead and use above nginx config to make your service accessible from outside network.

If curl doesn't work that means there is an issue with your backend service and you should debug that first.

Answer (score 0):

uwsgi_pass is not http protocol but uwsgi protocol which accept socket not http

when you do uwsgi_pass testing it expects socket so you need to run your uwsgi in socket mode and verify permissions on it (nginx should be able to read write to that file)

if you want to keep it at port and http you will have to change the uwsgi_pass into proxy_pass